# What is this memory region for?

Tags: c, virtual-memory

When I run my C program and I check its /proc/PID/maps file, I see this three lines about the executable:

1:

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 38404099 /previous_path/a.out
```

2:

```
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:03 38404099 /previous_path/a.out
```

3:

```
0601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:03 38404099 /previous_path/a.out
```

I think that the first one stores the code and the third one stores the global variables, but I have no idea what is the second for. Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Constant data? Literal strings? Could be any. Or none.

Comment: My guess: the 'x' (executable) section is the program's instructions, the 'w' section is for non-const data, and the 'r--p' is for RO data.

Comment: Hmm, I recognize these addresses, but in an OS that has nothing to do with posix.  You do have to mention what you use to get an accurate answer, the loader is an OS-specific implementation detail.

Comment: @HansPassant I agreed : we need some intel concerning compiler/production chain, production OS, target platform etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer this in a general mode. An executable is a set of instructions that directs the loader how to set up the program's address space. The loader is going to map pages into the process address space following those instructions.

All valid pages are going to readable. So you are only dealing with combinations of

Executable (X) and Writable (W)

That gives the possible combinations of

```
R
RX
RXW
R W
```

RXW is unusual but is does occur. I have seen applications that encode their instructions and decode at run time. We can ignore that case. Realistically one is left with:

```
R      Readonly (Data, such as strings or numeric constants, tabular data)
RX     Code
R W    Read Write (static, global, stack, heap, etc.)
```

If you have something like

```
 const char something [] = "SOMETHING" ;
```

The text SOMETHING is likely to go in a read only page.